# JS files upload queue using Django block

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django project, and a HTML template like this.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/second.js"></script>
<!-- ...
```

Imagine I have a file named `first.js` in `base.html`.
The question is that `second.js` seems to load BEFORE `first.js` which seems counter-intuitive to me. Do I have any control over the load queue of js files ?
Besides, it seems strange to me that first.js loads after second.js, one reason being using libraries, like, say, jquery.js which I use in second.js. Therefore, if base.html would always load after second.js, I would have numerious errors in second.js file (at least stemming from inability to recognize jquery functions).

All in all, my intuition is that normally base.html files should load before second.js, but I have come across an occasion when second.js file loaded before one of the files in base.html.
Can anyone shed light on the reason this could happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It entirely depends on where first.js exists in relation to second.js in the HTML.

The browser has no knowledge of Django, or blocks, or templates. All it sees is the rendered HTML. If the content block is included in the parent template at a point that is before the one where first.js is included, then it will be loaded first.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked a minor detail. It's ok now